# How to edit html in the body of Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I am curious as to how to edit content in the body of my Magento website. I can find and edit the header and footer with ease, but if there's anything in the body I seem to get lost as to how I can alter things. Why can't it just be as easy as hitting the delete button when using firebug:p

Comment: This is my second Magento website, so I'm really new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-->You can edit content of `CMS pages` in the `admin section` by going to `CMS->Pages` selecting the `page` and in the `CONTENT` section you can place `Images,Text,Static Blocks` etc.

-->To edit any other pages which doesn't belong to CMS pages you can edit them using '.xml' and `.phtml` files like for example if you want to edit Products list page you need to edit `catalog.xml` and `list.phtml`  which will be located in `template/catalog/product` of your theme file by adding respective `reference names` for example if you want to edit `content` the you need to make changes under `<reference name="content">` please feel free to get more information if needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can check first for cms page using as home page from

```
system -> configuration -> general(Web) from left bad -> Click on default pages tab from right
```

check drop down called **CMS Home Page**

and search same title in `CMS -> pages -> title column`

you can edit cms page from content or may be using some xml tag to display in body